# Postfix - Cannot set myhostname

Tags: debian, postfix

I simply fail to set **myhostname** for postfix. I am running Debian 6.0.

I simply want to call:

```
postconf -e "myhostname = mail.mydomain.com"
service postfix restart
```

in order to prevent mails getting rejected by some servers for lacking fqdn hostname.

But it is simply ignored. My main.cf shows:

```
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
```

But:

```
postconf -d myhostname
```

yields

```
<machine-hostname>.localdomain
```

just like before. As if I never changed anything.

What's the matter? ;) Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `postconf -d` will show you the default value for the config parameter. Just remove the `-d` and use the following instead

```
$ postconf myhostname
```

and you should get the current value. See `man postconf` for more info.

Comment: Haha, thanks a lot. And sorry for my stupidity. Clear case of rtfm.